# Open tomcat manager on a server over VPN ssh

Tags: java, tomcat, ssh, vpn

My server hardware is in a data center and I have no direct access to it. The telecoms company that owns the data center have agreed to allow me to access the server by ssh through a VPN.  So I connect to a VPN and from there ssh into my server.

Is there any way at all by which I can access the tomcat manager application   with this configuration?

Comment: Have you tried simply using HTTP access to it? And if you have SSH access to the server, then you can change the config and manage your web applications/files. [Configuring Tomcat Manager Application Access](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Comment: As said above, I'd try to access the Tomcat over HTTP (using the port tomcat is configured to run, i.e. 8080 if you haven't changed the configuration). If that's not possible, you can use [SSH Port Forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) to map a local port to the Tomcat's port on your server.

Comment: I connect to my vpn on url a. That is only where I can ping the destination server from. Does your suggestion still apply?